# Why multiple user connecting in One to One chat?

Tags: firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-firestore, agora.io, agora-web-sdk-ng

I created app on Agora.io one to one SDK. It is a random voice call app. When I start searching in 2 devices then both connect each other on call. That is okay. But when I am searching in third device then 3rd device also connecting in this room in which two already connected. So there 3rd device should not connect in this room it should search till any 4th device does not search. Please help me in this problem. I'm stuck on this so random voice call can't work because all user can connect in same room. While it should be one to one.

Comment: Hey there, could you please provide us more details about how are you trying to perform these actions (code, Error messages, logs, etc.)? Also, Firebase tags were added on this question. How does Firebase or Firestore are interacting with your scenario?

Comment: i need to make one to one private video calls with agora video sdk android The problem is a third person should not be merged in my current running video the person should wait for another 4th person to come online he must not merge into current running video call how should i resolve this? what should i do in order to make one to one calls thanks in advance. It should be one to one where only 2 people connect with each other not should be group

Comment: My application logic should make the third person wait for the fourth person before joining the channel. How can I do that?

Comment: Got it. I'm just curious. The tags of this question suggest that Firebase Realtime-Databases and Firestore are related to this. Could you please confirm if they are actually part of your current development? How do these systems interact with your chat application?

Comment: when user tap on search, inside firebase one node will create which name is searching 

inside search node other second user data who search from other place it will match the criteria, 
 if criteria successfully matches, firebase search node will delete and that 2nd user will connect with each other with agora

Answer (score 0):

In order to achieve the one to one video call, you can use the Agora RTM SDK. To do that, before a user joins the RTC channel (video call channel), he should also join the RTM channel with the same channel name as the one used for video call. Then you can use “getMembers” method in RTM SDK to retrieve a list of users in that channel. If there are already 2 users in this channel, this user should be blocked from joining in the channel.

“getMembers” api: https://docs.agora.io/en/Real-time-Messaging/API%20Reference/RTM_java/classio_1_1agora_1_1rtm_1_1_rtm_channel.html#a567aca5f866cf71c3b679ae09b4bf626